# Volley error output the error message sent from server side

Tags: android, android-volley

Am using volley with php and returning an error with the following structure as seen in postman

```
{
  "name": "Exception",
  "message": "Unable to verify your accont",
  "code": 500,
  "type": "yii\\base\\UserException"
}
```

Now i would like to read the error message above so in my volley string request i have

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(this.request_method, this.api_url,
            response -> {

             },
            error -> {
            //here process the error
            if (error instanceof ServerError || error instanceof AuthFailureError){
             NetworkResponse response = er.networkResponse;
             switch (response.statusCode){
              case 500:{
               HashMap<String, String> result = new Gson().fromJson(....); //stuck

               }
             }
            }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }         
    };
```

Am stuck on how to read the error message from volley error. How do i proceed with or without gson

I still want to use string request as i expect my response from php to be a json encoded string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way to read Response from `NetworkResponse`

For kotlin

```
val response = er.networkResponse
val jsonError = String(response.data)
val responseObject = JSONObject(response)
val message = responseObject.optString("message")
```

for java

```
NetworkResponse response = er.networkResponse;
String responseData = new String(response.data,"UTF-8");
JSONObject responseObject =new  JSONObject(response)
String message = responseObject.optString("message")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String errorResponse = new String(error.networkResponse.data);
```

Then convert this string to your json object

Answer (score 0):

try to get response.errorbody from your api response